# store data in browser

Tags: reactjs, session, caching, client-side

I have a scenario for some reason for my current reactJs app, some data need to store on the client-side for 15 minutes.
Suppose I have an  API 'x'. when a user first time hits this API after login, the response will be stored on the client-side for 15 minutes, within this 15 minutes stored data will be represented for each hit on the 'x' API. After this 15 minutes if the user hits the 'x' API stored data will be refresh with new data.

The response data size is around 50KB.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store some data on client side you can use `localStorage` for that.

- To set:-

```
localStorage.setItem(response, "responseData")
```

- To get:-

```
localStorage.getItem(response).  //will print "responseData"
```

Since the size of your response is 50kb you can use this as it's limit is 5Mb.